# Возможно ли работать на Android с локально лежащей на девайсе базой MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных, sqlite

Добрый день!
Собственно использую sqlite в своем приложении, но тут задался вопросом, а можно ли работать точно так же, но с MySQL? Чтобы файл БД был на устройстве.

**UPD:** это вопрос открыт ради удовлетворения любопытства, я не собираюсь делать такие вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то люди компилируют мускуль для андроида. И даже умудряются [продавать](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb), хотя я не знаю, насколько это законно.

[Здесь](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/28/percona-server-on-the-nexus-7-your-own-mysql-database-server-on-android-tablet/) описывают, как поставить мускуль на планшет.

Вот ещё [ссылочка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571911/running-amp-apache-mysql-php-on-android).

То есть - все реально. Но вот смысла никакого. sqlite достаточно хорошо справляется с поставленной задачей, он, можно сказать, интегрирован в систему.

Answer (score 0):

Ну у Вас и фантазия. MySQL это клиент серверная СУБД. На чистом андроиде - нельзя, т.к. нету MySql сервера, а без него в локальном файле - никак, да и врятли. На рутованый, чисто теоретически, можно наверное портировать мускул сервер, но андроид тут уже и особо и не причём.

Ещё наверное вариант - написать сервис который будет шарить локальный файл бд, а на сервачке у себя где-нить настроить мускул чтобы он базу сторил на этом расшареном диске - но скорость будет... :-)

А Вам зачем вообще Мускул с базой на девайсе?

Comment: мне это не за чем :)
просто интересно стало :)
а есть ли альтернативы sqlite, и чем они лучше/хуже?

Comment: Ну, есть Mimer SQL, есть Cellica... А смысл? Вы уже исчерпали все возможности sqlite и упёрлись в невозможность что-то сделать, или в её неэффективность?

Comment: @klopp нет, я не собираюсь никуда переходить, мне стало интересно, вот я и решил спросить :)